# Draw horizontal line in ListView to show dropping place

Tags: c#, winforms

When in Foobar2000 I drag-and-drop files into playlist, the ListView shows the place of dropping tracks:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to implement this feature. Is it just drawn by Graphics library, or do I have some implemented method to show horizontal line on ListView?

Comment: This looks like a ListView control, rather than a ListBox… Can you check that your question is accurate?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.insertionmark(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Cody, The `ListView.InsertionMark Property` is only for re-ordering items and only in a few modes.

Comment: @TaW It's not only for re-ordering items (or, at least, the underlying Win32 implementation isn't---you can display it anywhere you like, for whatever reason. I'm pretty sure the managed wrapper works the same way, but can't remember for sure). However, you're right that it only works in icon view, small icon view, and title view. It also requires comctrl32.dll version 6, so requires XP or later with Visual Styles enabled. And it doesn't work when groups are turned on. So yeah, definitely some limitations. Drawing your own is a more general solution, but I'd use the built-in whenever possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least with a `ListView` control, there is some limited built-in support provided by way of the [`InsertionMark` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.insertionmark.aspx), but this only works in icon view, small icon view, and tile view. It doesn't work when the Items are sorted or when groups are turned on, and it requires comctrl32.dll version 6 (thus meaning Windows XP or later, with Visual Styles enabled).

If you want a more general solution, you can easily draw a line yourself in the `DragOver` event:

[image: animated demo of effect]

To avoid flicker we remember the last index:

```
int prevItem = -1;
```

The event uses a `HitTest` to determine the item under the cursor..:

```
private void listView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point mLoc = listView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    var hitt = listView1.HitTest(mLoc);
    if (hitt.Item == null) return;

    int idx = hitt.Item.Index;
    if (idx == prevItem) return;

    listView2.Refresh();
    using (Graphics g = listView1.CreateGraphics())
    {
        Rectangle rect = listView1.GetItemRect(idx);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Top);
    }
    prevItem = idx;
}
```

If you want to use a `ListBox`, the code is pretty much the same:

```
private void listBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point mLoc = listBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    int idx = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(mLoc);
    if (idx  < 0) return;
    if (idx == prevItem) return;

    listBox1.Refresh();
    using (Graphics g = listBox1.CreateGraphics())
    {
        Rectangle rect = listBox1.GetItemRectangle(idx);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Top);
    }
    prevItem = idx;
}
```

Also do a `Refresh` to clear the line in the `DragLeave` event and also in the `DragDrop` event!

Note the this is one of the rare situations when you want to use `control.CreateGraphics` because the drawing is meant to be non-persistent! Normally all graphics should be drawn with the `e.Graphics` object in the `Paint` event!

Comment: Thanks! I accidently used ListBox where i should use ListView.

Comment: When in doubt, always go for `ListView` as it so much more powerful!